# node express global try catch instead of specific ones

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to setup an `express` app to catch any `throw new error` from a centeral function instead of many `try` and `catch`

```
var app = express();

tenantsRouter.get('/my_endpoint', async function(req, res, next) {
   
    var result = await methodThatCouldFail()

    res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({result);
});

app.use(apiPrefix + '/tenants', tenantsRouter);




error_handler = function(err, req, res, next) {

  console.error(`general error catcher - ${err}.`)

  return res.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json({
    'error': 'we are on it.'
  })


}
// error handler
app.use(error_handler)
```

The thing is, unless I use specific `try` and `catch` in `my_endpoint` the  `error_handler` doesn't catch `throw new Error` inside the methodThatCouldFail();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **only** API that Express provides to pass errors down the chain of handlers is via the `next()` function. You need to wrap it around something that will do the try/catch and call `next()` for you:

```
function asyncHandler (f) {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        f(req, res, next).catch(next)
    }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
tenantsRouter.get('/my_endpoint', asyncHandler(async function(req, res, next) {
    var result = await methodThatCouldFail()

    res.status(HttpStatus.OK).json({result);
}));
```

Which would work exactly how you expected it to work.

There are actually several implementations of this simple module on npm if you don't feel like writing it yourself including this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-handler

Comment: Thanks, tried your method and it didn't work but I used `express-async-handler` and it worked. thanks!

Comment: Ah. Sorry, forgot to await the function.

Comment: it's not passing the request to the endpoint function `f`. it's fine. just using the `express-async-handler`

Comment: This thing is, is that the stack trace is ruined. I can't seem to trace back to the error this way. tried `console.trace(`general error catcher - ${err}.`);`

Comment: The stack is not what you expect because all asynchronous functions, either via async/await or promises or callbacks are not called where you add the code. They are called later. So the stack starts at the event loop.

Comment: is there a way around it to show the exact place of the error?

Comment: Yes. Don't convert the error object to string. You are throwing away all details of the error when you do ``console.error(`general error catcher - ${err}.`)``. The location where the error happened is described by `err.stack` which is a string. What I often do is `console.log('Error:', err.code, err.message, err.stack)`